# extracting substring before a random numeric value: Xpath/XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have following string:  /abc/xyz/asdsd/sdfggf/10203940:40:50:/etc/oa.setup009

I need to extract string /abc/xyz/asdsd/sdfggf/  The numeric value after this string is dynamic, any possible way to iterate from left to right and moment you get number, you keep the sub-string before that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Hi, I am using XSLT 1.0, i was trying to convert all the numeric values to 00(constant value) and then getting string before that. But regex is not supported in this case as I am using XSLT1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the substring before the first digit in the given string, you can use:

`substring-before(translate($string, '123456789', '0'), '0')`

---

Note that if the given string contains no digits, the result will be an empty string.